# How to run a Flutter script

Tags: flutter, benchmarking

I'm trying to do some benchmarks on a library for flutter, however I do not know how to run a script that requires a flutter library. The only way I'm able to do it, is by running it as test code, however I do not find a way to disable assertions on test mode.

Works:

- flutter test myScript.dart (cannot disable assertions)

Fails:

- dart myScript.dart : Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'
- flutter run myScript.dart : can only run it on an emulator, not in my computer

Answer (score 0):

To run a script requiring a flutter library, I use the "pub" tool:

```
flutter packages pub run lib/script.dart
```

Comment: That didn't work, same problem about import dart:ui

Answer (score 0):

I was reading and trying to figure this out myself. It appears in order for this to work you have to include the .dart in the file extension as well.

So make sure your script is in the root directory's bin folder

```
/bin
/lib
main.dart
```

Then call `flutter pub run script.dart` from the projects root directory via terminal/cli and it'll look inside the `bin` directory for `script.dart` calling just `script` won't find the script unless the extension is missing. Pass any arguments like you would normally and it should work just fine.