# How do I run a command line tool that depends on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

The `flutter_test` package is able to run Flutter apps 'headless', without requiring any embedder. It would be useful to me to be able to run a *command line tool* (i.e. not a test) in the same mode. Is this possible? I looked at the `flutter_test` package but nothing there seems to be the magic solution.

What I've tried:

- Running a CLI tool that depends on Flutter with `dart path/to/tool.dart`. This throws `Error: Not found: 'dart:ui'`.
- Running it with `flutter run path/to/tool.dart`. This will attempt to start the CLI tool as a regular Flutter app on a device (such as an Emulator, the desktop OS, or a web browser).
- Running with `flutter pub run path/to/tool.dart` just generates a lot of errors, such as `"Error: 'Paint' isn't a type"`. I tried all approaches suggested in [this related SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56861264/how-to-run-a-flutter-script), with the script living in various directories and using different invocations, but no luck.
- Running the tool using `flutter test path/to/tool.dart` does work, and it runs the code in `main()` like one would expect. But I consider this a hacky workaround, since `flutter test` (unsurprisingly) expects a test, and exits with the error "No tests were found." And, semantically, it's just wrong. This is not a test. It's a tool.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code relies on `package:flutter` or `dart:ui`, you won't be able to run it outside of a Flutter engine instance (e.g., `flutter_tester` or a Flutter application) as `dart:ui` is a custom core library for Flutter that isn't part of Dart's core libraries. Short of hacking away at `flutter_tester` to remove the test runner related logic or creating your own custom embedder of the Flutter engine, you won't be able to run a Flutter project headless on the command line.

Ideally, you'd just refactor your tool to not depend on `dart:ui` at all, but given your background I'm guessing you're trying to do something non-standard that actually requires functionality from the Flutter framework... :-)

Comment: Thank you! It's great to have a confirmation from someone on the team. I don't really mind the relative hackiness of using `flutter test` — I just wanted to make sure I'm not missing something. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @filiph - we have a similar use case: I'd like to render a widget to a file directly on the server. Did you end up with a solution?